# confused by substring result of stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

my code

```
NSMutableString *s= (NSMutableString *)[@"http://www.yahoo.com/index.html" stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

what I expected result of s is

```
http://www.yahoo.com
```

but the code above show s is:

```
http:/www.yahoo.com
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: It's not a path, it's a URL.  Convert it to `NSURL` and use some it's methods to process it.

Comment: And your attempt to cast this to `NSMutableString` is wrong. All you are doing is lying to the compiler since it is not really a mutable string.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `NSURL`, not `NSString`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com/index.html"] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

Yielding:

> http://www.yahoo.com/

If you absolutely need a string from this, you can then do:

```
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
```

Or, if you really needed a mutable string, don’t cast it to `NSMutableString`, but do create a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableString *urlString = [url.absoluteString mutableCopy];
```

But, in general, where possible, you should stay with `NSURL` when dealing with URLs. And when tempted to use file paths, use file URLs instead.

Comment: File URLs aren't "true URLs"?

Comment: I’ve removed the offending term. Lol.

Comment: I don't believe the cast is need in your last snippet since `mutableCopy` returns `id`.

Comment: I’ve removed redundant cast.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation for this method is explained as follows。

Apple Document: Note that this method only works with the file paths (not, for example, the string representations of URLs).

But you string is clearly a full URL address, does not belong to the file path, so we will assemble them into a URL, using URL classification URLByDeletingLastPathComponent to intercept

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yahoo.com/index.html";
NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSURL* lastPathUrl = [URL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString* lastPathString = lastPathUrl.absoluteString;

NSLog(@"---%@---", lastPathString);
```